# Why is a sleep required? ksh/bash

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

I have the following functions

```
get_previous_term() {
@var term=$1
@var centry=${term:0:2}
@var year=${term:2:2}
@var semester=${term:4:2}

case $semester in
    10)
    semester=$((semester+30))
    year=$((year-1))
    ;;
    # years stay the same
    20)
    semester=$((semester-10))
    ;;
    30)
    semester=$((semester-10))
    ;;
    40)
    semester=$((semester-10))
    ;;
    *)
    error_exit "Unknown Term $term"
    ;;
esac;
@var prev_term=$((centry))$((year))$((semester))
echo $prev_term
}

get_n_terms_ago() {
@var term=$1
@var counter=$2
@var tmp=$term
@var i=0
while [ $i -lt $counter ]; do
    tmp=$(get_previous_term $term)
    term=$tmp
    i=$((i+1))
done;
echo $term
}
```

(The @var is just typesetting (part of the oo-bashframework))

Now the question is this. Say I want to get 3 of the previous terms from a term that start with 201610 as such.

```
   current_term="201610"
   previous_term=$(get_previous_term $current_term)
   previous_2_term=$(get_n_terms_ago $current_term 2)
   previous_3_term=$(get_n_terms_ago $current_term 3)
```

If I set one variable by itself it works fine. If I do them sequentially I will get a command not found (from shell). I have been able to get it to reliably work by using sleep's between the variable assignments. Example

```
   current_term="201610"
   previous_term=$(get_previous_term $current_term)
   sleep 1;
   previous_2_term=$(get_n_terms_ago $current_term 2)
   sleep 2;
   previous_3_term=$(get_n_terms_ago $current_term 3)
   sleep 1;
```

I'm not sure what is happening? Does $() spawn another shell? Shouldn't the shell wait for the previous command to be completed? (Also if I omit the first sleep (even if i use get_n_terms_ago with n of 1) I will not have issues. Seems to happen on setting the 2/3rd variables.

Comment: Since this requires oo-bashframework, others can't run your code (without grabbing 3rd-party bits and sourcing them in). Can you generate a **standalone** reproducer someone else can use to reproduce the bug? (Use either `local` or `declare` keywords as alternatives to `@var`).

Comment: (Also, speaking for myself, I don't trust `oo-bashframework` much; it has rather considerably too much magic; the explicit bugs I've found on a code review have been fixed, but it also has enough complexity for it to be very hard to be certain of any review's completeness).

Comment: ...but, to answer your direct questions: Yes, `$()` spawns a subshell (via a fork with no exec). Yes, that subshell exits (or, at least, closes its stdout) before subsequent commands are run.

Comment: BTW, your code has numerous quoting issues which http://shellcheck.net/ would detect.

Comment: ...I'd also suggest using `set -x` to log what the script is actually doing at runtime, to see precisely what it's trying to run when you get the "command not found".

Comment: I don't have the oo-bashframework, so I stripped out the `@var` keywords. But I was able to run your program, without @var, successfully, producing results that I think are correct (201540 ... 201520). I'm using

`GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`

Comment: Thanks Charles will look into the quoting issues. - not a shell programmer :-|.. That is correct output Austin not sure why I need the sleeps will look at fixing issues Charles has brought up and continue testing. Thanks for the input guys

Comment: Charles - Thank you so much. I ran my code through the shellchecker.net fixed a few issues here and there (quoting) and now my code works fine without the sleeps - Not really sure exactly why... but happy the issue is resolved.